# Secondary project based on original branched project (in GIT)

Tags: php, git, laravel, branch, git-branch

We have a project that we've been working on for 4 years. We're launching a similar product that will be based extensively on the other project. In fact, Project B will start with Project A's code and then be tweaked to the specifications of Project B.

We would like for all changes in Project A, now and in the future, to be incorporated into Project B, however, we do not want any changes to make it back to Project A.

We've started with Project A being on master/origin branch, and then having a separate branch for Project B. However, I worry about Project B getting merged into master accidentally by myself or another developer. Is there a better way to accomplish what we're trying to do?

For the record, both projects are PHP/Laravel projects.

Comment: You can always rollback if B accidentally gets merged into A. But you probably know this? But I guess it would be quite a mess if A makes more commits after the accidental merge.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm worried about. It wouldn't be done intentionally but it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `projectB` another *repo*, instead of another branch.

From `projectB` repo, you can:

- add projectA url as a remote (`git remote add projectA /url/for/projectA`)
- fetch `projectA` repo
- merge `projectA/master` whenever you want.

But even if you were to push (from `projectB`) to `projectA` by accident, there would be no modification of `projectA` master.